# Correct way to define json schema with enum and pattern

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have json schema like below:
Please let me know correct way for json schema for above value. So as to use `enum` along with `pattern` to validated the values

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "items": 
      {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "p1": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["ABC","pqr"]
          },
          "p2": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["{{1}}","{{2}}","{{3}}"],
            "pattern":"*"
          },
          "p3": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": ["p1","p2"]
      }
}
```

I want to validate below set of values:

value: `[{"p1":"pqr", "p2": "{{1}}_{{2}}_{{3}"}]`

Please let me know correct way for json schema for above value. So as to use `enum` along with `pattern` to validated the values

I tried using pattern having _ in it but not getting validated correctly

Comment: The enum keyword allows to define a set of possible (valid) values. Your sample data for the p2 property has a combined string with some underscores. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: Ok, I see. You want to combine the pattern keyword with the values from the enum as a regular expression? This is not supported and the validator won't do this for you.

Comment: any other way to validate it through schema?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, combining values from `enum` isn't possible. Instead you can try using `pattern` with a regex.

I'm not sure about the combination constraints you have but the regex could look like `^{{[123]}}(_{{[123]}})*$` if you want to support arbitrary combinations of those `{{1}}`, `{{2}}`, `{{3}}`. You can modify the regex to suite your needs if you have a max number of repetitions, want to enforce an order etc.

In a schema it would look like this (minimal example with only `p2`):

(note the ugly escaping of the curly braces)

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "p2": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^\\{\\{[123]\\}\\}(_\\{\\{[123]\\}\\})*$"
            }
        },
        "required": ["p2"]
    }
}
```

which allows `[{"p2": "{{1}}_{{2}}_{{3}}"}]` but rejects `[{"p2": "{{1}}_foo_{{3}}"}]`